# Resetting/Clearing a global array of pointers to structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm new to C and I'm having a bit of a problem resetting or clearing a global array of pointers to structs.
I need to receive a file (or more) and read it's lines in two cycles.
while reading it I need to create a table of symbols(labels basically), and then use it to create more data (exporting the location of the labels to files writing it in hexadecimal values).

The problem I am having is when I'm reading two files. The first file is read fine and all the values are correct, but when it tries to read the second file the values in the table(array) I created are still there even though I free'd them.

I have this declared in a header file: (SIZE being 30)

```
typedef struct symbol{
unsigned action :1;
unsigned external :1;
int address;    
char label[SIZE];
unsigned data_flag :1;
} symbol ; 

symbol *symbol_Table[SIZE] ;
```

An example of adding a new symbol: (this sits in the reading function)

```
new_symbol =  malloc(sizeof(symbol));
strcpy(new_symbol->label, temp);
new_symbol->external = 0;
new_symbol->address = DC - tok_count; 
new_symbol->action = 0;
new_symbol->data_flag = 1;
add_symbol(new_symbol);
free(new_symbol);
```

The adding function, in a different file: (**UPDATE**)

```
if(count == SIZE){
    **/*realloc the array size, increase it*/**
}

if(count < SIZE){
    symbol_Table[count] = malloc(sizeof(symbol));
    symbol_Table[count]->action = new_symbol->action;
    symbol_Table[count]->external = new_symbol->external;
    symbol_Table[count]->address = new_symbol->address;
    strcpy(symbol_Table[count]->label, new_symbol->label);
    symbol_Table[count]->data_flag = new_symbol->data_flag;

    /*printf("count: %d\n", count);*/
    return ++count;
}

return count;
```

And the freeing of the symbols at the end of the reading loop: (**UPDATE**)

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < count ; i++){
    free(symbol_Table[i]);
    symbol_Table[i] = NULL;
}
```

this is the correct output after the first loop on the first file:

```
action: no | extern: yes | address: 0 | label L3 | data: no
action: no | extern: yes | address: 0 | label W | data: no
action: yes | extern: no | address: 100 | label MAIN | data: no
action: yes | extern: no | address: 106 | label LOOP | data: no
action: yes | extern: no | address: 119 | label END | data: no
action: no | extern: no | address: 0 | label STR | data: yes
action: no | extern: no | address: 7 | label LENGTH | data: yes
action: no | extern: no | address: 10 | label K | data: yes
```

and the faulty output after the first loop of the second file: (**UPDATE**)

```
action: yes | extern: no | address: 100 | label MAIN | data: yes
action: no | extern: yes | address: 0 | label W | data: yes
action: yes | extern: no | address: 108 | label LOOP | data: yes
action: no | extern: no | address: 0 | label STR | data: yes
action: no | extern: no | address: 3 | label K | data: yes
```

should be:

```
action: yes | extern: no | address: 100 | label MAIN | data: no
action: no | extern: yes | address: 0 | label W | data: no
action: yes | extern: no | address: 108 | label LOOP | data: no
action: no | extern: no | address: 0 | label STR | data: yes
action: no | extern: no | address: 3 | label K | data: yes
```

A few questions:

1. Is there a way to clean the list after I used it? and then reusing the same list for new values? and avoiding the memory leak.
2. Is this idea with arrays just a waste of space, should I try using linked lists instead? I fear that I will have to write my whole project again, and time is not on my side..

(**AFTER UPDATE**)

3. How can I Reallocate more memory to increase the size of the array when I reach its end?

Apologies if I misused a term, I'm studying C in a different language.

Comment: Freeing a pointer releases the memory to which it points; it does nothing to the pointer value itself.

Comment: I suggest maintaining a counter that indicates how many of the leading elements of your array contain valid values.  As this to check entry validity *by index*, rather than assuming that non-NULL pointer values are valid.

Comment: Alternatively, just explicitly set each pointers to NULL after freeing it.

Comment: And you should set (and control) a limit to avoid an overflow on `symbol_Table`.

Comment: I see what you mean, using a known index seems like a better idea.

Comment: With an index though, you won't be clearing space that you've already used and you'll hit your size of 30 quickly. There is no point of even freeing memory in that case. This is because you check if an index is NULL before adding data, so all of your new data appears at the bottom.

Comment: Your problem is in the fixed size for the symbol table: `symbol *symbol_Table[SIZE] ;` Normally, you want it varable, enabling you to resize the table, when needed.

Comment: But I still need to choose an initial size don't I? otherwise I'm just adding symbols to something that doesn't exit, no?

Comment: You need to pick an initial size. Zero is a good choice (realloc() works fine if its first argument happens to be NULL) Please see my answer.

Comment: I still haven't resolved the problem, so I don't know if any of the answers is correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are freeing your structs, your data is not immediately overwritten since the heap allocator isn't required to; it just makes a note that the space you freed is available. You should go one step further, and set each index of your array to NULL after freeing them. That will actually remove them from your array.

Now, I would be cautious when using an array. You have specified a size, but you aren't enforcing it in your add function.

If you swap your array over to use dynamic memory by using malloc, and you reach the size constraint later in the program, you can allocate more space using `realloc` (which would basically allow you to implement an ArrayList without disturbing the rest of your program's implementation).

To initially allocate space for your array, try:

```
symbol **symbol_Table = (symbol *) malloc(sizeof(symbol *) * SIZE);
```

---

**Note:** malloc can only be called from *inside* a method. So, at the top of your file, you can declare your variable:

```
symbol **symbol_Table;
```

Then, before using it, you should define it in your `main()` method:

```
symbol_Table = (symbol **) malloc(sizeof(symbol **) * SIZE);
```

---

Note the notation in the malloc statement - you need to multiply the size of
the array with the size of a symbol pointer, because malloc takes the number of bytes that are to be allocated. `sizeof(symbol *)` gives you the size of a single `symbol` pointer.

Also: in order to use realloc, the initial allocation of `symbol_Table` should be something returned by malloc / calloc / realloc, or NULL.

If you're just trying to pop the reallocation into your if-statement, try:

```
static size_t current_size = SIZE;

if(count == current_size) {
  current_size = current_size << 1;
  symbol_Table = (symbol *)realloc(symbol_table, sizeof(symbol *) * current_size);
}

if(count < current_size) {
  // ... the rest of the code continues here
```

The bit about `current_size << 1` is a bitshift left - it effectively multiplies `current_size` by two.

Static variables retain their values between function calls. So, if I change it when I call the function one time, the next time I call the function, the variable will have the value I set in the previous call. The reason for the static variable is that the value of current_size should be saved between calls if you increase the size of your array, and that you have to store the size of the array somewhere. The best place to store it is in the one function where the real size of the array is important - the only place where it will be upscaled. A global variable would work just as well though.

---

To free the symbol table at the end:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < count ; i++){
  if(symbol_Table[i] != NULL) // Important - we cannot free NULL
  {
    free(symbol_Table[i]);
    symbol_Table[i] = NULL;
  }
}
count = 0; // Important - if we are deleting everything in the array, we
           // need to make sure we reset the count for our next delete
           // operation
```

Comment: Would you suggest adding a function to 'realloc' when the symbols reach its limit? or is that just bad coding and I should try to write everything again as a linked list?

Comment: Realloc wouldn't be bad coding in my opinion. ArrayLists are as widely used as LinkedLists, and realloc would essentially be establishing exactly that (which I had updated my answer to say :p you may be looking at an older version of it). So I wouldn't consider it "bad coding". Your space requirement in that case would be O(n) roughly, but make sure you double the capacity with each realloc to keep the number of realloc calls down.

Comment: How can I realloc memory to increase the size of the array?

Comment: If you call realloc with a pointer that was previously allocated with malloc, it will copy the data over to a new block and give you a new pointer to wherever the data was moved. But, your block will have more space than it did before, if you provide a larger size than the original block's size. Refer to https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are calling realloc with some pointer p, you should not call free on p. You should free the pointer returned from realloc when you are done with it.

Comment: I added a small bit of code to demonstrate how you can use realloc.

Comment: I'm getting an "error: initializer element is not constant" when trying to create the initial array.

Comment: Also thank you for all your help! I love the idea of doubling the size by shifting the bit :)

Comment: How are you creating the initial array now? Would you mind updating your example?

Comment: I tried switching with the code you suggested. I'll update the code when I'm next to a computer.

Comment: Oooohhh - malloc calls can only happen in methods. You should declare the variable in its current position, then *define* it by using malloc in the main method. I'll update my answer.

Comment: after allocating memory for the whole array, how should I free it at the end of the two loops? somthing like running a loop with free(symbol_Table[i]) gives me the error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘free’

Comment: I am aware of the rule of 1 free command for 1 malloc, but maybe I should just free the whole array instead of free each 'symbol'?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't accidentally calling free with NULL at some point?
Try an if-statement: `if(symbol_Table[i] != NULL) { free(symbol_Table[i]); } symbol_Table[i] = NULL;`

Comment: I added a bit about freeing at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: error: invalid operands to binary != (have ‘symbol’ and ‘void *’)
when trying to implement the clear function..

Comment: Oops, that mistake's on me. You should be declaring symbol_Table as a double pointer, or pointer to a pointer, since it is a dynamically allocated array of pointers. If you change that, your code should work.
If not, I may be able to help more if you provide a pastebin with the rest of your code.

Comment: Is there a way to still have the adding function in a different file? When I do so, I get 'symbol_Table' is undeclared. Do I know have to add the symbol_Table to every function that uses it?

Comment: Yeah. You could also use global variables (i.e. declare it in a header file, and include the header file in every c file that uses symbol_Table), but generally, passing around data as arguments to functions is preferable.

Comment: @ Anish Goyal  after a lot of fiddling with the code, I believe it's now working correctly! I can't thank you enough! so THANK YOU, again! :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is (IMO) that `SIZE` is a constant. If you make it variable you could resize the symbol table when needed.

The cleanest way is to store the array of pointers *together with the size(s)* in some envelope-structure, like in:

---

```
struct symbol{
        unsigned action :1;
        unsigned external :1;
        unsigned data_flag :1;
        int address;
        char label[SIZE];
        } symbol ;


struct symtab{
        unsigned size;
        unsigned used;
        struct symbol **table; /* used as an array of pointers */
        };

        /* global: for fun */
struct symtab thetab = {0,0,NULL};

int resize_the_thing(struct symtab *sp, unsigned new_size)
{
struct symbol **newtable;

        /* Note: realloc takes care of copying, too ...*/
newtable = realloc (sp->table, new_size * sizeof sp->table[0]);

if (!newtable) { /* handle error */
        return -1;
        }

sp->table = newtable;
        /* TODO: you need to check the case new_size < size here, too */
sp->size = new_size;
return 0; /* no_error */
}

/* typical usage: */

if (thetab.used >= thetab.size && resize_the_thing( &thetab, 12345)) {
        /* report error */
        }

thetab.table[thetab.used++] = new_symbol(...);
```

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but will do when I get back home! thank you! :)